# How do I start/charge a Toro Electric-Start Lawnmower?

Tags: lawn-mower

We just got a Toro electric-start "Recycler"-brand lawnmower.  The instructions for charging/starting it reference a strange plastic piece that I don't understand.

Here's the piece of plastic:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are the instructions from the "quick start" guide:

[image]

And here are the instructions on the mower itself:

[image]

Based on the quick-start instructions, it seems I need to have the plastic piece in one orientation when charging, then to run it I need to take it out, rotate it, and replace it?  But it's not clear which orientation is which.

And based on the instructions on the mower, I'm supposed to push it in to start the mower... except it doesn't push in any further than its base-position, so that can't be right.

I'm so confused right now.  How do I use this thing?

Comment: Is there some packing in the button hole preventing the button from moving down when pressed? Have you charged the mower for 24 hours?

Comment: Did you pull the running handle switch to the fixed handle before you pushed the start button?

Comment: it is a start key .... see last picture .... 1. insert key, 2. pull lever, 3. press key

Comment: the quick start page .... step #7 ... choose between electric start (top of page) or manual start (bottom of page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions direct the button to be put in only one way. The curved arrow does not mean to flip the button over; it means the button causes the engine to turn.

When you stop the mower it directs removal of the button and taking it away (so some unauthorized user can't start the mower just by pulling the bail and pressing the button).

Comment: This turned out to be correct.  After putting the button in, you have to push _really_ hard to get it to snap in.  After that, it functions as a normal button.